# Modifying user input data

Tags: r, shiny, visualization

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("data", "Select data:",
                     c("Iris" = "iris",
                       "Cars" = "mtcars")),
  plotOutput("myPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dat <- reactive({
    switch()
  })
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    dat <- switch(input$data, 
                  "iris" = iris,
                  "mtcars" = mtcars)
    plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = get(input$data))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Above is a simple app that prompts the user to select a data set, and then plots a graphic using a data set. I wanted to modify it such that the user can specify some value, `t`, that also gets passed into the `plot` statement.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("data", "Select data:",
                     c("Iris" = "iris",
                       "Cars" = "mtcars")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("t",
                  "Scale:",
                  min = -5,
                  max = 5,
                  value = 2, step = 1,
                  width = "100%")

    ),
    mainPanel( plotOutput("myPlot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dat <- reactive({
    switch()
  })
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    t = input$t
    dat <- switch(input$data, 
                  "iris" = iris,
                  "mtcars" = mtcars)
    plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length * t, data = get(input$data))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, I get the following error statement: `variable lengths differ (found for 't')`. What I'm hoping to achieve is to append a `t` column to the user input data set. I've tried `dat$t = t` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing calculations inside a `formula` (`Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length * t`), you need to [use I() to bracket the portions of the formula where the operators are used in their arithmetic sense](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html):

```
plot(Sepal.Width ~ I(Sepal.Length * t), data = get(input$data))
```

**Update:** If you want to do many kinds of manipulation of the data, I would suggest to create a reactive function (`dat`) to calculate the data based on user input, and then use the `data.frame` object returned by `dat()` as input data in your plot:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  dat <- reactive({
    if (input$data == "iris") {
      df <- iris
      # Do any calculations based on user input (here input$t)
      df$Sepal.Length <- df$Sepal.Length * input$t
    }
    df
  })

  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = dat())
  })
}
```

To make this work across multiple data sets, have the dat() function rename the dependent (`Sepal.Width` in `iris`, something else in `mtcars`) and independent (`Sepal.Length` in `iris`) to e.g. `y` and `x` and then use `plot(y~x, ...)` in your plot (or write a separate plot function for each data set).

Comment: Thank you. It worked for this toy example, but my actual function is a bit more complicated, and using the I() bracket doesn't seem to work. I'm actually hoping that once I get the user input data, I can append a new column, t, to it. So that when plot calls the user input data set, the t will be inside the iris data set